# ModelMapper: What is the best way to solve this

Tags: java, modelmapper

I have a problem with `ModelMapper` library.

Entity classes:

```
abstract class AbstractEntity {
    Long id;
}
class User extends AbstractEntity {
    String login;
    Business business;
}
class Business extends AbstractEntity {
    String name;
}
```

Dto classes:

```
class NewUser {
    String login;
    Long businessId;
}
```

How I simulate the problem:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NewUser newUser = new NewUser();
        newUser.setLogin("jhonatan.serafim");
        newUser.setBusinessId(1L);

        ModelMapper mapper = new ModelMapper();
        User user = mapper.map(newUser, User.class);

        System.out.println(user.getId());
        System.out.println(user.getLogin());
        System.out.println(user.getBusiness().getId());
    }
}
```

Expected:

> null
>
> jhonatan.serafim
>
> 1

Actual:

> 1
>
> jhonatan.serafim
>
> 1

What is the best way to solve this?

Comment: please describe your problem in words as well as the code block to make it easier for those who want to help.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately it does not work the way I quoted above, but using with strict mode me meets the need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use strict matching strategy:

```
mapper.getConfiguration().setMatchingStrategy(MatchingStrategies.STRICT);
```

But in this case `user.getBusiness().getId()` will fail, because `NewUser` does not have `business` field.

More about matching strategies: [ModelMapper – Configuration](http://modelmapper.org/user-manual/configuration/#matching-strategies)

Comment: please have you tried to fix this in strict (case where business is null)

Answer (score -1):

Why would you expect the `id` to be `1`?  You didn't set it to `1` in the `NewUser`.  Set it there and it should work as expected.